# Struts 2: s:if inside s:iterator not working

Tags: struts2, if-statement, iterator

I have a question regarding struts 2 and s:if tags. As per described on the documentation of s:if the following example was supposed to work:

```
...
<s:iterator value="questao.alternativas" status="alternativa">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:if test="#alternativa.correta == true">Correta!</s:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
...
```

But this is not working on my case, could you please help? More details:

questao.alternativas is found on the action and it works fine, all "alternativas" are "iterated"!

the getCorreta() method is never call on the example described above.

when using  the value true is printed.

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `status` in `iterator` tag will push an instance of [IteratorStatus](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) on value stack. You need to consult the documentation of IteratorStatus for valid attributes to use and *correta* is not a valid attribute. If you want to access the current iteration's object specify a `var` attribute instead.

**Edit for comment:**
That's right as Quaternion said you don't need to specify `var` for accessing current iteration's object. It's already on top of value stack.

Comment: +1, because of the reference to the documentation.  Do not use the var attribute, unless you have nested iterators.  Inside the iterator the current object is at the top of the value stack. If alternativas has an attribute called "correta" replace your current if statement with: <s:if test="correta == true">Correta!</s:if>... yes it is that simple...

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking at your code I see that you are referencing the status in your conditional(if) statement. Your conditional should directly reference the accessor method of the object in the list your are iterating through, for example:

```
<s:iterator value="questao.alternativas" status="stat">
    <tr>
        <td>
            // If correta is a boolean value, there is not need to use an 
            // == operator at all
            <s:if test="%{correta}">
                Correta!
            </s:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

When an iterator traverses a supplied list, assuming questao.alternativas is a list of objects with accessor methods, you directly reference the methods inside your iterator.

The status in an iterator gives you access to the iterator's position. For example, if you want to determine if your loop is at the last element in the list to perform something special you would do something like:

```
<s:if test="%{#stat.last}">--- END OF LIST ---</s:if>
```

Or to get the indexed position of the current element in your array or list:

```
<s:property value=%{#stat.index} />
```